# unable to install Laravel via composer on Windows 7: "29 packages you are using are looking for funding"

Tags: php, json, laravel, composer-php

I have installed Composer on windows 7 with the **Composer-Setup.exe**.

I am trying to install Laravel via Composer on Windows 7. I've tried 2 different commands:

```
composer global require laravel/installer
```

and

```
composer create-project laravel/laravel blog --prefer-dist
```

but they don't work.

In the end, there always a message: "29 packages you are using are looking for funding"

[image]

When I type composer fund to find out, it says that:

> Composer could not find a composer.json file in C:\Users\Administrators

Does any one have any solution or any useful link?

Comment: Your composer.json file have some packages which have paid licence. However composer do not prevent installing Laravel due to this. As per logs Laravel has been successfully installed. Can you check at the destination folder.

Comment: I verified the folder and indeed, it works. Thanks a lot!

Comment: Posting it to answer so other can take benefit.

Answer (score 0):

Your `composer.json` file have some packages which have paid licence. However composer do not prevent installing Laravel due to this.

As per logs Laravel has been successfully installed. Can you check at the destination folder.